# Parsing string to decimal throws a FormatException for DateTime

Tags: c#, parsing, decimal, formatexception

I have a Web project which has data of different tools, Im able to insert and delete tools into a RadGrid (which is connected to a database), but Im having issues with the edit command

One of the values of the tools is "Cost" which is decimal, when Im trying to edit, half of the time it gets me this error:

> "Input String was not in correct format error"

This is my Edit Method when the user clicks on the edit form modal to submit the edit

```
protected void btnMdlEditar_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           NumberStyles style;
           CultureInfo provider;
           style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
           provider = new CultureInfo("en-US");
           decimal costoDecimal;
           var costo = editCosto.Text;
           costoDecimal = decimal.Parse(costo.ToString(),style,provider);
           try
           {
               var id = CDatos.DHerramientas.UpdateHerramientas(int.Parse(txtId.Text), editCodigo.Text, editNombreCorto.Text, editDescripcion.Text, costoDecimal, editConsumible.Text);
               rgHerramientas.DataBind();
               rgHerramientas.Rebind();
               upHerramientas.Update();
               this.ShowMessage(Resources.Language.mess_insert, "success");

           }
           catch (Exception ex) { this.ShowMessage(ex.Message, "danger"); }
           this.CloseModal("mdlHerramientaEdit");
       }
```

In the line

> costoDecimal = decimal.Parse(costo.ToString(),style,provider);

Is where I get the error, with a FormatException poping up, mentioning an issue while parsing a string to DataTime, for some reason.
I have no idea why Im getting this error when Im using the exact code to parse decimal from string in my Insert Method

```
protected void btnAutorizar_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
       {
           NumberStyles style;
           CultureInfo provider;
           style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
           provider = new CultureInfo("en-US");
           decimal costoDecimal;
           var costo = txtCosto.Text;
           costoDecimal = decimal.Parse(costo.ToString(),style,provider);
           try
           {

               var id = CDatos.DHerramientas.InsertHerramientas(txtCodigo.Text, txtNombreCorto.Text, txtDescripcion.Text, costoDecimal, txtConsumible.Text);
               this.upDatos.Update();
               this.ShowMessage(Resources.Language.mess_insert, "success");

           }
           catch (Exception ex){this.ShowMessage(ex.Message, "danger"); }
           this.CloseModal("mdlHerramienta");
       }
```

When I edit the data by only deleting some a part of the number or when the number is not changed it throws the error, but if I delete the number completely and enter another decimal number, it allows me to edit it

```
7.85 to 7.89 = Error

7.85 to 6.12 = No error
```

Im already have

> using System.Globalization;

And my current culture is "es-ES"

Edit: 
I tried to delete the "provider" from

> costoDecimal = decimal.Parse(costo.ToString(), style, provider);
>   which allows me to edit succesfully if I only change part of the number, but if I type a new number using "." it throws me the error again

I think the issue is using "." instead of "," which is the method used in Spain for decimals, is there a way to use both "." and ","?

Comment: Why does the title say "for datetime"?

Comment: `Excepción producida: 'System.FormatException' en mscorlib.dll

Información adicional: La cadena de entrada no tiene el formato correcto.`                         

Exception produced in 'System.FormatException' en mscorlib.dll                             
"Input String was not in correct format error"

Comment: That does not address my question.  "DateTime" is not in your code anywhere, so its inclusion in the title is confusing.

Comment: Im not using DateTime at any point in that code, its the Exception Debug which brings up "DateTime" when parsing string to decimal for some reason that I dont understand, it shows at a suggestion: ""When converting a string to DateTime, parse the string to take the date before putting each variable into the DateTime object."

Comment: Read the words in the exception message carefully.  DateTime is mentioned as *an example*

Comment: Do you want to accept more than one culture format? If no, put some validation / masking client side to reduce the chance of passing in the wrong format, and then strictly only accept one on the server. If yes, cascade some `decimal.TryParse` calls, falling down to the next if the first one fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, the issue origin was using "," instead of "."

Because of the nature of my project I have to use culture as "es-ES" for the entire project.

If "." was used instead of "," it threw the error, so to be able for the users to use "." and the system to use "," I had to change the code

```
protected void btnMdlEditar_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            NumberStyles style;
            CultureInfo provider;
            style = NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint;
            provider = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            decimal costoDecimal = 0;
            var costo = editCosto.Text;
            if (editCosto.Text.Contains("."))
            {
                costoDecimal = decimal.Parse(costo.ToString(), style, provider);
            }
            else if (editCosto.Text.Contains(","))
            {
                costoDecimal = decimal.Parse(costo.ToString(), style);
            }

            try
            {
                var id = CDatos.DHerramientas.UpdateHerramientas(int.Parse(txtId.Text), editCodigo.Text, editNombreCorto.Text, editDescripcion.Text, costoDecimal, editConsumible.Text);
                rgHerramientas.DataBind();
                rgHerramientas.Rebind();
                upHerramientas.Update();
                this.ShowMessage(Resources.Language.mess_insert, "success");

            }
            catch (Exception ex) { this.ShowMessage(ex.Message, "danger"); }
            this.CloseModal("mdlHerramientaEdit");
        }
```

Changing the culture depending if "," or "." was used